# End of text dissapears in TextView

Tags: php, android, text, textview

I have some issues with the app I made recently.
It's supposed to connect to a Raspberry and execute a PHP page, which uses preg_match_all to filter 3 text documents and show 3 lines of text along with the date and time of today.

The issue I have is that when the text is over 5 lines long (which is almost always the case) the last line just dissapears from the TextView and is just not visible.

I tried a lot of things from other forums but nothing seemed to help (that also means my code could be a little messy)

So, here's the **MainActivity** code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private HttpClient mHttpClient;
TextView result;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new connectTask().execute("");
    result = findViewById(R.id.result);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "connexion", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    if (VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new Builder().permitAll().build());
    }

}

public class connectTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, HttpClient> {
    @Override

    protected HttpClient doInBackground(String... message) {
        mHttpClient = new HttpClient("http://192.168.0.51", new HttpClient.OnMessageReceived() {
            @Override
            public void messageReceived(String message) {
                publishProgress(message);
                Log.d("doInbackGround", "recu " + message);
            }
        });
        mHttpClient.run();
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    @RequiresApi(api = 24)
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {

        super.onProgressUpdate(values);


        String resu = result.getText().toString();
        resu = resu + values[0];

        result.setText(Html.fromHtml(resu, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
        result.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

    }

}
}
```

And this is my **XML layout** for the MainActivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="8"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_height="391dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:freezesText="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[And this a picture preview of what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ex92c.png)

It's supposed to continue and write "PHARMACIE " and the other words, just like the other lines

Comment: Did you try android:layout_height="wrap_content" on TextView?

Comment: May I assume that you are not having any issues retrieving the data in `HttpClient`? If that is indeed the case, you can remove that part of the code from your this post.

Comment: I will try your suggestion and answer to the person that asked it as a formal question.
Yes, that part is working, I therefore removed it from the question, thanks!

Comment: I removed my answer because I misunderstood the result you wanted. I thought you wanted to only show a maximum of 5 lines in the `TextView`. But what you really want is to show the lines you take from the document and show those lines in their entirety in the  `TextView`?

Comment: Not at all you got it right the first time, I'm opening 3 txt documents and using preg_match_all to get 1 line from each document. I'm also showing the date and time, so it's approximately 5 lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

Basicly, the HTTPClient I was talking about before editing my post was a class I imported, and it included [the following restriction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cdvO.png).

I removed the cap and am now able to see the whole text. I still can't see the linebreaks on the app that I clearly see when I connect to my raspberry per browser but I guess that is another problem which will result in another thread, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

in your `TextView` correct the height like so:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Oh! and as mentioned above the attr. `maxLines` should be removed

Comment: After trying out the suggestion with both "android:layout_height="wrap_content"" and "android:maxLines="5"", I removed the one concerning the maxLines, but I'm still getting the same result

Comment: I believe the problem is within the `ConstraintLayout` itself then because it is still in the early development stages, try a Relative/Linear layout and don't forget to remove the constaintLayout properties also get rid of attr. `freezesText`